Problema na Conversão de Bytes em C++
Estou desenvolvendo um programa em C++ para converter um valor dado de bytes para unidades como KiB, MiB, GiB, etc., seguindo as convenções IEC e SI. No entanto, estou encontrando dificuldades com a precisão dos resultados. Abaixo está o trecho relevante do meu código:
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void convertBytes(long long bytes, bool iecConvention) {
    std::string resultBytes = "";
    std::vector<std::string> notation;
    std::vector<double> conversionFactors;

    if (iecConvention)
     {
      notation = {"Bits", "Bytes", "KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB"};
      conversionFactors = {1 / 8, 1, std::pow(1024, 1), std::pow(1024, 2), std::pow(1024, 3), std::pow(1024, 4),
                        std::pow(1024, 5), std::pow(1024, 6), std::pow(1024, 7), std::pow(1024, 8)};
     } else {
      notation = {"Bits", "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"};
      conversionFactors = {1 / 8, 1, std::pow(1000, 1), std::pow(1000, 2), std::pow(1000, 3), std::pow(1000, 4),
                         std::pow(1000, 5), std::pow(1000, 6), std::pow(1000, 7), std::pow(1000, 8)};
     }

    std::cout << "Conversão para unidades " << (iecConvention ? "IEC" : "SI") << ":" << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < notation.size(); ++i) {
        double value = bytes / conversionFactors[i];
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << value << " " << notation[i] << std::endl;
        bytes = bytes % static_cast<long long>(conversionFactors[i]);  // Atualiza bytes para o restante
        resultBytes += std::to_string(std::round(bytes)) + " " + notation[i] + " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    long long bytes = 1208925819614629174706176LL; // 1 Yottabyte em bytes

    convertBytes(bytes, true);  // Usando convenção IEC
    convertBytes(bytes, false); // Usando convenção SI

    return 0;
}


A saida que o programa esta retornando:
Conversão para unidades IEC:
-nan Bits
Floating point exception (core dumped)

Já mudei as variável conversionFactors=1024 e conversionFactors=1000 e ainda assim nao consegui ajustar a logica para converter o valor de 1YiB para as quantidades de bits,MB,GB, TB.. Tanto na notação SI quanto na notação IEC. Qual seria a melhor maneira de resolver este problema?

A conversa ficou longa demais e foi movida para o chat.. Utilizem o link para consultar/participar. Antes de postar um novo comentário, revise a proposta dos comentários.

O valor que usou, com 25 dígitos ---e para uma variável com sinal --- está muito acima do possível de armazenar nas plataformas comuns, que usam oito bytes para esse tipo.
Em geral não há muito sentido em usar sinal para quantidades. E o sinal é um bit então o valor que pode representar cai para a metade. Um char pode ter de -128 a 127, mas um unsigned char vai de 0 a 255 por exemplo.
O compilador é seu amigo. Considere esse programa:
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(unsigned long long int);
    unsigned long long int teste = 0;
    unsigned char*         p     = (unsigned char*)&teste;
    cout << "(" << size
         << " bytes para unsigned long long "
            "int)\nValor = 0x";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
        *(i + p) = 0xff, cout << std::hex << (int)*(i + p);
    cout << " = " << std::dec << teste << " (decimal), com "
         << (int)(1 + std::log10(teste)) << " digitos\n";
    return 0;
}


que mostra até onde pode ir na sua máquina
Uma possível saída:
(8 bytes para unsigned long long int)
Valor = 0xffffffffffffffff = 18446744073709551615 (decimal), com 20 digitos

